# Any way to have *all* keystrokes sent to remote system with Microsoft Remote Desktop app or other RDP/VNC client?

Tags: keyboard, windows, remote-desktop

I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop to connect from a Monterey box to a Windows 10 box. The Windows 10 system has dozens of idiosyncratic keyboard shortcuts. Some of them work via the RDP connection but many do not, presumably because they are recognized and trapped by MacOS. I've seen guides to manually overriding individual keyboard shortcuts on a per-app basis, but it would be a lot of work to go through every possible keystroke and make sure that MacOS isn't catching them, and even then I'm not sure it will be fully effective.

So I'm wondering: is there a global solution that would allow every keystroke combination to be sent to the Windows remote system, rather than having to solve this on a one-off basis? If not with Microsoft's client, is there another client that implements this better? If it's not possible to have 100% of keystrokes sent, what's the best way to get as close to that goal as possible?

Comment: macOS is always going to intercept a command first, unless you disable or change it it locally. It's the same with much of Apple RDC, not just MS.

Comment: So is there any systematic way to disable or change *all* local shortcuts on a per-app basis? Or do I just need to hunt down every conflict and manually remap/disable?

Comment: If they're global, basically you're stuck with them. *Some* you can reassign, like commands to interact with Mission Control/Spaces, but you're not going to be able to intercept cut/copy/paste [though as MS uses Ctrl not Cmd you shouldn't need to do it for most macOS shortcuts. It might help if we knew which commands are being troublesome.

Comment: One issue is task-switching--I'd like ALT-TAB to switch within Windows when on Remote Desktop, but to otherwise have the same key combination trigger task switching in MacOS when not in Remote Desktop. (I'm using a Windows keyboard for all of this). But maybe it's not possible to have the same combination behave differently depending on context.

There were other idiosyncratic shortcuts not working in Windows, like CTRL-SHIFT-; . But I went through shortcuts in MacOS and just disabled everything, which seems to have fixed most issues (albeit leaving me without those shortcuts in MacOS).

Comment: idk what Ctrl/Shift/; does on Windows, but it's unlikely to also be a Mac command unless you're in some kind of terminal app. Alt/Tab equivalent on Mac is Cmd/Tab, so you kind of made that conflict for yourself by changing it.

Comment: Seems like the best solution for my particular situation is to set any overlapping key combinations to an unused combination (either in MacOS or on the remote Windows system), then create rules in Karabiner that re-map the shortcuts depending on whether the active application is Remote Desktop or not. Thus, I can have ALT-TAB send CTRL-TAB in all circumstances other than when Remote Desktop is foregrounded, in which case ALT-TAB is sent. Then ALT-TAB works to task switch in both MacOS and on the remote system in the full-screen Remote Desktop session. Somewhat labor intensive but gets it done.

Comment: RDP is unusable in mac. There must be a solution to this problem cant just have random things happening in MacOS from keystrokes meant for the. remote machine. IM positive this worked several years ago but now seems impossible to use any RDP software on mac.